# Preencher variável com tipos diferentes

Tags: c#, .net, tipagem, conexão

Tenho muitos campos para pegar então fica muito ruim fazer uma função pra cada conexão e são bancos não mapeados então usar algo como o Entity Framework também não é viável

```
if (1 == 1) {
    OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(con);
    OdbcCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
} else {
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(con);
    MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
}
cmd.CommandText = "";
connection.Open();
```

O ponto é como preencher a mesma variável com 2 tipos de objetos diferentes, assim posso mudar apenas o método de conexão sem precisar fazer toda a query de novo.

---

Achei a solução, usar `dynamic`, assim ele aceita objetos diferentes e consigo acessar suas funções

```
dynamic sqlConn = null;
dynamic cmd = null;
if (1 == 1) {
    connection = new OdbcConnection(con);
    cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
} else {
    connection = new MySqlConnection(con);
    cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
}
cmd.CommandText = "";
connection.Open();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não dá para fazer isto assim.

Eu não sei se foi um erro (parece que não) ou foi proposital, mas a classe [`OdbcConnection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) não deriva de uma que dê para generalizar. Se foi proposital então deve ter um motivo, mesmo que não explicitado (há indícios na documentação), e deve ser diferente mesmo. Ela até deriva de algo genérico demais ([`Component`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.component?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)) que não pode ser usada aqui, teria que ser algo mais específico um pouco, veja a seguir.

Já a [`MySqlConnection`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnection.htm) deriva de [`DbConnection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0) que parece adequado. Se a outra classe derivasse dela também, e intuitivamente eu **acho** que deveria, mas também tem indicações que não deveria, então seria fácil resolver com um objeto de tipo mais genérico, o `DbConnection`.

Mas não tem isso e parece ter um bom motivo, então o certo é não generalizar, tem que fazer tudo separado mesmo. São lógicas distintas por inteiro, não é correto tentar juntar as duas, por mais que seja tentador.

ODBC tem várias limitações, trabalha a conexão de uma forma diferente e precisa de cuidados que uma conexão normal não precisa, por isso provavelmente fizeram ela diferente e não derivar de `DbConnection`, ou seja, pelo que está na documentação dá a ideia que é um erro fazer o que está tentando.

Eu nem estou entrando no mérito se isto tudo está certo. Será que tratar um banco de dados ODBC deve ser usado? Tem certeza? Isto é bem complicado funcionar certo, ainda mais tentar usar a mesma lógica para ele e para o MySQL. A não ser que não esteja usando a mesma lógica, então não faria sentido tentar juntar a conexão.

A solução parece ser outra, mas sem um contexto maior nem dá para começar ajudar. Parece até ser um [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/101).

Sem falar que boa parte dos códigos, até simples, de conexão que vejo postados aqui tem problema e complicações desnecessárias, não posso afirmar que é o caso pela falta de contexto, mas pode ser que tenha outros problemas, até mesmo a desnecessidade do uso do ODBC.

E não use `dynamic` para fazer uma gambiarra. Pode funcionar, mas não está certo. Este comando foi criado para casos onde você não tem controle sobre a composição do objeto. Neste caso tem controle. Menos ainda inicie algo com `null`, quase em todos os casos isto é sinal de erro. Está criando um problema para consertar o problema real. Está funcionando por coincidência.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Comment: Essas funções que uso pegam de mais de 50 campos da tabela, As tabelas tem a mesma estrutura só que são em bancos diferentes, fazer 1 função para cada banco faria q uma modificação em algo precisa-se ser feita nas 3 funções e deixaria o código bem maior, por isso usei essa solução.

Comment: Não se criar a abstração certa, ou seja, é um problema XY.

Comment: Não acredito que  isso seja considerado como resposta para pessoas que estejam com o mesmo problema,  mas como não posso colocar  a pergunta como resposta vou marcar a sua para  fechar o tópico.