# Qual é a forma correta de fazer um "Replace()" em uma variável do tipo string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, desempenho, replace

Preciso criar uma pasta no servidor de arquivos e percebi que a variável que recebe uma das informações está vindo com caracteres inválidos (`\ / : * ? " < > |`) para a criação de pasta no Windows.

```
string Caminho = Path.Combine(PastaPadrao,txtInfoUser.Text);
```

No caso do carácter (:), ele é relevante para o usuário e por isso precisa ser gravado, mas nada impede que eu faça um `Replace()` para *underline*, porém pintou a dúvida: Qual é a forma correta de fazer o `Replace()` nesse caso?

```
return Caminho.Replace(@"\", "_")
               .Replace(@"/", "_")
               .Replace(@":", "_")
               .Replace(@"*", "_")
               .Replace(@"?", "_")
               .Replace(@"""", "_")
               .Replace(@"<", "_")
               .Replace(@">", "_")
               .Replace(@"|", "_");
```

Se eu fizer dessa forma, vão ser criadas 9 instancias diferentes da *string*?

Por hora, eu fiz dessa forma:

```
 StringBuilder CaminhoSemCaracteresInvalidos = new StringBuilder(Caminho);
CaminhoSemCaracteresInvalidos.Replace(@"\", "_")
                .Replace(@"/", "_")
                .Replace(@":", "_")
                .Replace(@"*", "_")
                .Replace(@"?", "_")
                .Replace(@"""", "_")
                .Replace(@"<", "_")
                .Replace(@">", "_")
                .Replace(@"|", "_");

return CaminhoSemCaracteresInvalidos.ToString();
```

A minha preocupação é em tentar fazer da melhor forma para que a aplicação não sofra no final do dia, sempre tentando fazer o que é certo do ponto de vista de performance e boa prática, mas também não sei se estou montando uma bomba atômica pra matar uma mosca.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Se eu fizer dessa forma, vão ser criadas 9 instancias diferentes da *string*?

Isso.

A segunda forma parece mais adequada porque não faz as alocações e alocação custa mais caro que as pessoas imaginam<sup>*</sup>, se for fazer isso em um laço com vários *paths* pode botar uma pressão enorme no *gargabe collector* e ficar dando pausas.

O `StringBuiler` permite alterar a *string* e o `Replace()` dele é *inplace*, mantendo só uma alocação além da original e depois outra para o resultado final. Acho que o `Caminho` poderia ser criado nela, assim já economia mais uma alocação.

Mas fico pensando se não vale a pena fazer um algoritmo que varra toda *string* (padrão ou *builder*, a última é mais fácil fazer com performance) e crie uma nova mudando o que precisa em um passo só. Explico.

A segunda forma ainda tem o problema que terá 10 laços (o `ToString()` também tem um) sendo executado em todo o texto. Você não está vendo mas está executando. Então se você fizer um laço que lide com todos os caracteres pode dar um resultado bem mais rápido. A outra resposta tentou fazer isto mas como continuou usando `Replace()`criou um problema exponencial que é tudo o que um desenvolvedor deve evitar (só não dá problema aparente em baixo volume).

Há como fazer com `RegEx` também, mas em todos os casos que eu já vi se fizer na mão fica mais rápido (já vi gente falando que o `RegEx` pode ser mais rápido, mas nunca vi acontecer quando comparado com código manual feito corretamente). Eu nem pensaria nisso a não ser que seja fanático por esse tipo de solução (eu acho que além de tudo fica ilegível, mas é gosto).

O ganho total pode ser brutal.

Muitas vezes a pessoa não se preocupa com isso porque vai usar pouco, aí anos depois essa pessoa, ou outra que nem trabalha na equipe hoje, vai usar de forma mais intensa e terá algo lento. Aí ninguém sabe o que é, e ficam desesperados com a lentidão e só olham pro código novo quando o erro é antigo.

Mas cada um sabe onde o calo dói, então precisa analisar se vale o esforço. Pra mim sempre vale a não ser que seja muito trabalho e sei que o ganho realmente não é necessário (raro isso acontecer pra mim).

---

<sup>*</sup>A alocação em si custa barato, mas colocando pressão no GC faz ele entrar em ação mais vezes e por mais tempo, e pior, fazendo trocar de geração outros objetos de forma prematura. Não é fácil perceber isso acontecendo, é algo que vai aos poucos, é mais ou menos silencioso (alguns são bem surdos e não escutam até quando tem um pequeno ruído), por isso se fizer um teste ingênuo parece até rápido.

Comment: Esse seu ultimo paragrafo resume bem a minha postura com relação ao resultado final. Hoje, com 10 usuários e 5 pastas funciona bem, mas e amanhã quando minha aplicação crescer? Tá pode ser que ela nem cresça, fique com 10 usuários a vida inteira, mas e ai? vou arriscar? Ainda tenho muito feijão  com farinha pra comer, mas o básico eu sinto que tenho a obrigação de fazer...

Answer (score 2):

Eu faço dessa forma. Não sei se é a mais correta, mas funciona.

```
public static string RemoveCharSpecials(string document)
    {
        var charsToRemove = new string[] { "@", ",", ".", ";", "'", "(", ")", "-", " ", "/" };

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(document))
            {
                foreach (var c in charsToRemove)
                    document = document.Replace(c, string.Empty);
            }

            return document;
    }
```

Comment: "Não sei se é a mais correta, mas funciona." ...Então cara, essa é a minha preocupação...
Funcionar por funcionar, eu poderia fazer de N maneiras, mas o meu objetivo é buscar programar de uma forma que eu não arrebente a performance da minha aplicação. As vezes são pequenas atitudes que fazem toda a diferença.

Comment: Quando usei foi feito esse fragmento, foi com essa preocupação. havia uma outra q esta travando todo o processo e deixando mto custoso. Regex arrebentou de toda a forma @EduardoOliveira

Comment: A ideia é boa, mas ela provavelmente será a pior solução porque cria uma nova *string* para cada caractere encontrado no que já existe, ou seja será comum ter dezenas de `Replace()`s em quase todos os casos destruindo a performance. O certo é construir outra *string*.

Comment: @Maniero pelo mais incrivel q isto pareça teve um ganho, a string nela mesmo ajudou bastante. vc sugere qual ateração?

Comment: Prove que teve ganho. mas faça o teste em condições reais, usando uma metodologia de testes que funcione, de preferência o https://benchmarkdotnet.org/. Digo isso porque não faz sentido ficar mais rápido tendo um esforço maior e a única explicação é o teste ser feito de forma equivocada.

Comment: @Maniero está em prod e não houve mais reclamação. Isso por si já basta para comprovar q funciona. E qual a sua sugestão para melhora. uma coisa é a teoria outra a prática

Comment: Sim, eu concordo que não houve reclamação. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/425183/101 olha a foto que postei na minha resposta, o cara que tá usando não reclama de nada, tá servindo pra ele. Você não falou que funciona, você falou que ficou mais rápido, você deve ter uma prova disso, na prática, porque senão você está teorizando sobre ter ficando mais rápido. Se você conseguir fazer uma pergunta que não seja um "faz pra mim que eu quero ver" que não é objetivo do site, pode postar que eu responderei qual é a prática, vc já tem a teoria para ajudar fazer a pergunta, então comece fazer o código

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101813/discussion-between-celziobr-and-maniero).